# Calling an API and storing the data in to an SQL Server table

Tags: json, sql-server, api, parsing

Im trying to use a solution i got from Stackoverflow to call an api and parse the data in a tabular format. However im finding an issue in parsing the data due to the way its structured.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;`enter code here`
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'https://accaho.nanorep.co/api/report/v1/get.json?account=accaho&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxf&days=1&fields=source.time,source.kb_name,source.domain,content.query,content.resultFound,content.articleID,content.articleTitle,content.articleLabels,content.articleContext.Applications,translation.autoTranslated,translation.customersLanguage,translation.originalMessage,channel.rechanneled,channel.channelType,feedback.feedbackType,feedback.feedbackReason,feedback.feedbackText,count.resolved,count.interactions,count.feedback,count.feedbackPositive,count.feedbackNegative&kb=English', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
-- select the JSON string
select * from @json
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json), N'$.rows')
```

**I'm Kinda stuck here...** How can i parse this data in to a tabular structure. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse and get the values from `$.rows` JSON array, you need to use an additional `OPENJSON()` call, because the `$.rows` part of the input JSON is a JSON array of JSON arrays. The correct syntax depends on the JSON structure and you can parse the input JSON with [default or explict schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value):

Statement for parsing the `$.rows` part of the input JSON using default schema:

```
-- .....

SELECT j1.[value], j2.[key], j2.[value] 
FROM @json d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Json_Table, N'$.rows') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
```

Statement with columns definitions (column name and data type can be different):

```
SELECT j1.[value], j2.* 
FROM @json d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Json_Table, N'$.rows') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    Column1 varchar(100) '$[0]',
    Column2 varchar(100) '$[1]',
    ...
    Column21 varchar(100) '$[20]'
) j2
```

If you want to get column definitions from the `$.fields` part of the input JSON, you need a dynamic statement.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "fields":["source.time","source.kb_name"],
    "rows":[
        ["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com"],
        ["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com"],
        ["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com"],
        ["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com"],
        ["63725381755149","English","gph.accenture.com"]
    ]
}'

DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME([value]), N' varchar(max) ''$[', [key], N']'''), ', ')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.fields')
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT * ',
    N'FROM OPENJSON(@json, N''$.rows'') WITH (', @stm, N')'
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json nvarchar(max)', @json
```

Comment: Thanks for this. now i can see the row values as one  column. How can i make get those each value in to a Table column. My Table has 21 columns. Each value from this should go to corresponding columns...

Comment: This is one row of data: 

Key Values

0 63725391502961
1 English
2 gph.accenture.com
3 Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection
4 True
5 1518752271
6 Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection
7 Bot
8 Athena
9 False
10 
11 
12 False
13 
14 
15 
16 
17 1
18 1
19 0
20 0
21 0

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR You need a statement with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause with columns definitions). The answer is updated. Thanks.